# Не кодирует кавычки

Tags: php

Делаем так: `echo json_encode(['id' => 123], JSON_HEX_QUOT);`

На выходе получаем: `{"id":123}`

Не понимаю в чем проблема. Мне нужно закодировать кавычки чтобы вывести json в data атрибут html.

Comment: Ну так а вы обращались к `data.id` в js при ответе? `dataType` У вас json в аяксе стоит?

Comment: @RifmaMan при чем тут это? У меня разметка невалидная выходит из-за этого. Нет json не в аяксе. Он просто рендерится на сервере вместе со страницей.

Comment: Вы 123 пытаетесь обернуть в кавычки что ли?

Comment: вам результирующую строку эскейпить надо, а не опциями json баловаться. Имена полей в json всегда будут в двойных кавычках, это формат. Данная опция влияет на значения.

Comment: @RifmaMan у него `data-json="<?= json_encode(...)?>"`

Comment: @teran да, я именно об именах полей. А чем ее эскейпить тогда если не опциями json_encode?

Comment: @teran, теперь понял, спасибо )

Comment: Переведите id в строку и всего делов - `json_encode(['id' => (string)123])` Вам по этому php и выводит значение как число

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` или `htmlentiries` закодируют `"` в `&quot;` либо, если вы знаете, что в вашем json нет одинарных кавычек, можете дата атрибут в одинарные заключить, а не двойные.

Comment: @teran в моем json еще и html разметка есть =)

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК тогда вам точно нужно использовать `htmlentities()` дабы избежать конфликта с кавычками при вставки в html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

во первых, оставьте в покое сам `json`. Данный формат подразумеваем, что имена полей всегда заключены в двойные кавычки, как и строковые значения полей. Это формат, на него влиять вы не сможете.

Ваша проблема в том, чтобы вывести строку, содержащую двойные кавычки, в дата-атрибут.
Все что для этого надо сделать - чтобы в данной строке не встретилась двойная кавычка, и не нарушила разметку. Для этого следует заменить двойные кавычки в строке на их эквивалент - `&quot;`, для чего предназначены функции [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) (с параметром `ENT_COMPAT`) либо [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)